# How do I upload a Universal Python Wheel for Python 2 and 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pypi, python-wheel

I have a package on PyPi and when preparing a new release I build the source distribution, build the wheel and upload, all with setuptools.

However, I've found it only uploads the wheel for the Python version used in the upload command (`python` and `python3`).

Here are the steps I'm taking:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload
```

According to the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#universal-wheels):

> "Universal Wheels" are wheels that are pure python (i.e. contains no compiled extensions) and support Python 2 and 3

So that seems to be the right thing for me.

After the wheel build step, I verify the wheel is built and has the filename format `PACKAGE-VERSION-py2.py3-none-any.whl` in `dist` but when I run the upload with `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload`, it creates a `PACKAGE-VERSION-py3-none-any.whl` and uploads that.

If I run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload` it does the same for and uploads a Python 2-only one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The command `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload` creates a **new** wheel distribution.

You'll need to include the same flags again on that command line:

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --universal upload
```

It's better to use [`twine`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) to manage the uploads; it'll use an encrypted connection (`setuptools` uses an unencrypted connection and thus sends your username and password in the clear) and it allows you to inspect and test the distribution before uploading:

```
python3 setup.py sdist
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
# test the distributions
twine upload dist/*
```

Twine is currently also the only tool that [sets the 'Py versions' metadata for PyPI correctly for universal wheels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415349/what-does-the-py-version-in-pypi-project-page-mean-and-does-it-matter/40417563#40417563).