# What does the "Py Version" in PyPI project page mean? And does it matter?

Tags: python, setup.py, pypi, python-wheel

I notice that, most projects released on PyPI contain a "Py Version" meta data in their project page, but their values vary.

If the package is not a universal package or not a pure python package, their values are understandably different, in order to denote their targeted platform, such as this [nose page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose/1.3.7) and this [simplejson page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/3.10.0).

But some other universal pure (as far as I can tell) Python packages still contain slightly different content. For example:

- search "Py Version" in this [requests PyPI page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/2.11.1) you will find "2.7"
- In this [rsa page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsa/3.4.2) you will find "3.5"
- In [six page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/1.10.0) it is "py2.py3"
- In [python-dateutil page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.5.3) you will see "any"

So my question is, are they caused by different tool chain the author use to build their release package? My attempt of running `python2 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --universal upload` gives me a "2.7" Py Version value. Next time I will try `python3 ...` and then `twine ...` to see what I will get.

More importantly, do all these matter? My aforementioned command line still builds a universal package suitable to be consumed by others on Python 2 AND Python 3 environment, doesn't it?

Comment: Since this question was asked, the pypi design appears to have been changed to de-emphasize "py version."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anywhere you see `2.7` or `3.5` or another Python version, that column was set [by the `bdist_wheel` command](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/src/54ddbcc9cec25e1f4d111a142b8bfaa163130a61/wheel/bdist_wheel.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#bdist_wheel.py-250), based on the *current Python version used to build with*, but this is the wrong value. This is [bug 102](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/issues/102) in the Wheels project issue tracker.

This was also [reported as a bug](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/450) in the PyPI project. It really should say `py2.py3` for all those projects. Luckily, it doesn't matter to the tools used to install wheels what that column says, you still have a universal wheel, it'll be used for installations on either Python 2 or Python 3.

This is not PyPI's fault however, the field is set *by the tool doing the uploading*. The [`file_upload()` XML-RPC handler](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/blob/7d45be8888ed8d28b9fa32183866512f452d073c/webui.py#L2866) takes the value unchanged from the uploader and inserts that into the database for later display. When using `setuptools upload` that value is ultimately sourced  from the code that built the distribution file, so `bdist_wheel` in this case.

If you care deeply about your own project listing the correct information there, then I recommend you use the [`twine` uploader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine) instead; this package [extracts the `pyversion` field from the wheel filename](https://github.com/pypa/twine/blob/master/twine/wheel.py#L49-L52). Any project that has `py2.py3` set in the *Py Version* column, used that tool to do the uploading. Twine has many other advantages, not least that you can use it to *securely* upload your files over HTTPS.

As for the `any` value, that's either set by manually uploading a file in the PyPI interface , or perhaps another tool or a previous version of `twine` or `setuptools bdist_wheel` I'm not aware about.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was asked, the PyPI design has removed "Py Version" from project pages; the Py Version seems to have been related to the wheel tags or the version of Python used to upload the package, and would not affect which versions of Python can download a source package.

PyPI does feature the [Requires-Python](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#requires-python) metadata `Requires: Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*` if it is available. This tag is independent of the package format, and a relatively new feature in pip, that controls whether or not the installer will attempt to install a particular project in the target version of Python.