# Wheel files : What is the meaning of "none-any" in protobuf-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Tags: pip, protocol-buffers, armv7, python-wheel

I used pip to get .whl file for numpy

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=./ numpy
```

and I have got  `numpy-1.13.3-cp27-cp27mu-linux_armv7l.whl` because I am using ARM platform, but when run pip for protobuf

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=./ protobuf
```

I got `protobuf-3.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

So, why isn't `linux_armv7l` like the case of numpy, I didn't alter the machine and searched for that difference but no information.

thanks for advice .

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30438216/1959808 for creating "universal" wheels (`python3 setup.py bdist_wheel` creates a `py3` wheel by default. `python3 setup.py bdist_wheel --universal` creates a `py2.py3` wheel, if possible).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Let's split package names by components:

- numpy — package name
- 1.13.3 — package version
- cp27 — the package was compiled to be used with this version of Python
- cp27mu — compilation flags
- linux — operating system
- armv7l — processor architecture

This means that package `numpy` contains binary extensions written in `C` and compiled for specific processor, OS and Python version.

The following package is pure Python:

- protobuf — name
- 3.4.0 — version
- py2.py3 — the package is written in highly portable manner and is suitable for both major versions of Python
- none — is not OS-specific
- any — suitable to run on any processor architecture

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, but can I get .whl file of protobuf and specific for particular architecture like ARM7l ? , or that depending on the remote repo. for that package ?

Comment: Yes, that depends on what the author publishes. Google [provides](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/protobuf/3.4.0) binaries only for 64-bit Linux on amd/intel processors. For the rest `pip` downloads the portable package and compiles from sources.

Comment: This is partly wrong, the other answer by wolfhong (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50712035/3194671) is more correct.

Comment: In particular, "none" in the second wheel name is the abi tag, while "any" is the platform (OS + arch) tag - the corresponding values from the 2 examples are actually `cp27 <-> py2.py3`, `cp27mu <-> none` and `linux_armv7 <-> any`

Answer (score 19):

The wheel filename is `{distribution}-{version}(-{build tag})?-{python tag}-{abi tag}-{platform tag}.whl`.

### distribution

Distribution name, e.g. 'django', 'pyramid'.

### version

Distribution version, e.g. 1.0.

### build tag

Optional build number. Must start with a digit. A tie breaker if two wheels have the same version. Sort as the empty string if unspecified, else sort the 
initial digits as a number, and the remainder lexicographically.

### language implementation and version tag

E.g. 'py27', 'py2', 'py3'.

### abi tag

E.g. 'cp33m', 'abi3', 'none'.

### platform tag

E.g. 'linux_x86_64', 'any'.

[reference is here.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention)