# tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. (Raspberry pi 4 )

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi4, python-wheel

i'm installing tensorflow on raspberry bi 4 4gb ram i followed this step: [Q-engineering](https://qengineering.eu/install-tensorflow-2.2.0-on-raspberry-pi-4.html)
but when i do install the framework it gives me the error

```
tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

my raspberry pi run armv7l and it's fresh new Raspbian os

pip version : 22.0.4

python version: 3.9.2
anyone can help me fix this error

Comment: Python version: **3.9**. Wheel: **cp37**.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46915474/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem

first I download the 64 bit OS from the raspberry pi website
then i go [here](https://github.com/PINTO0309/Tensorflow-bin/tree/main/previous_versions) and search tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-none-linux_aarch64
cp39 because it's python 3.9 and arrch64 because 64bit